# Extracting German words with regex

Tags: python, regex, text, nlp, nltk

I have some large **German text files** (that I can split into smaller text files, so that's not a problem) from which I want to **extract the words** and later count how many times a each word appears (the latter is also not a problem).

The texts are pretty messy:

```
'''Alan Smithee''' steht als [[Pseudonym]] für einen fiktiven Regisseur, der Filme verantwortet, bei denen der eigentliche [[Regisseur]] seinen Namen nicht mit dem Werk in Verbindung gebracht haben möchte. Von 1968 bis 2000 wurde es von der [[Directors Guild of America]] (DGA) für solche Situationen empfohlen, seither ist es '''Thomas Lee'''.<ref>[[Los Angeles Times|latimes]].com: [http://articles.latimes.com/2000/jan/15/entertainment/ca-54271 ''Name of Director Smithee Isn't What It Used to Be''], zuletzt geprüft am 2. April 2011.</ref> ''Alan Smithee'' ist jedoch weiterhin in Gebrauch.

Alternative Schreibweisen sind unter anderem die Ursprungsvariante ''Al'''len''' Smithee'' sowie ''Alan Sm'''y'''thee'' und ''A'''dam''' Smithee''. Auch zwei teilweise asiatisch anmutende Schreibweisen ''Alan Smi Thee'' und ''Sumishii Aran'' gehören – so die [[Internet Movie Database]] – dazu.<ref name="IMDb">[http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000647/ Eigener Eintrag für ''Alan Smithee'' in der IMDb]</ref>

== Geschichte ==
=== Entstehung ===
Das Pseudonym entstand 1968 infolge der Arbeiten am Western-Film ''Death of a Gunfighter'' (deutscher Titel ''[[Frank Patch – Deine Stunden sind gezählt]]''). Regisseur [[Robert Totten]] und Hauptdarsteller [[Richard Widmark]] gerieten in einen Streit, woraufhin [[Don Siegel]] als neuer Regisseur eingesetzt wurde.

Der Film trug nach Abschluss der Arbeiten noch deutlich Tottens [[Manier (Stil)|Handschrift]], der auch mehr Drehtage als Siegel daran gearbeitet hatte, weshalb dieser die Nennung seines Namens als Regisseur ablehnte. Totten selbst lehnte aber ebenfalls ab. Als Lösung wurde  ''Allen Smithee'' als ein möglichst einzigartiger Name gewählt.<ref>[http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000647/bio ''Biography for Alan Smithee''] in der Internet Movie Database</ref>

In den zeitgenössischen Kritiken wurde der Regisseur u.&nbsp;a. von [[Roger Ebert]] mit den Worten gelobt: 
{{Zitat
 |Text=Director Allen Smithee, a name I’m not familiar with, allows his story to unfold naturally. He never preaches, and he never lingers on the obvious. His characters do what they have to do.<ref>rogerebert.[[Chicago Sun-Times|suntimes]].com: [https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/death-of-a-gunfighter-1969 ''Death of a Gunfighter''], zuletzt geprüft am 2. April 2011</ref>
 |Sprache=en
 |Übersetzung=Regisseur Alan Smithee, ein Name, der mir nicht vertraut ist, erlaubt es seiner Handlung, sich natürlich zu entfalten. Er predigt niemals, und er verweilt nie beim Offensichtlichen. Seine Charaktere tun, was sie tun müssen.}}

=== Aufdeckung und Abkehr ===
1997 kam die Parodie ''An Alan Smithee Film: Burn Hollywood Burn'' (deutscher Titel ''[[Fahr zur Hölle Hollywood]]'') in die Kinos, was das Pseudonym einem größeren Publikum bekannt machte, nicht zuletzt weil [[Arthur Hiller (Regisseur)|Arthur Hiller]], der eigentliche Regisseur des Films, selbst seinen Namen zurückzog und analog zum Filmtitel das Pseudonym ''Alan Smithee'' benutzte. Der Film gilt als einer der schlechtesten Filme der 1990er Jahre und gewann fünf [[Goldene Himbeere]]n.

Der Film ''[[Supernova (2000)|Supernova]]'' ist der erste Post-Smithee-Film, dort führte ein gewisser ''Thomas Lee'' alias [[Walter Hill]] die Regie.
<!-- fand nur einen für den von 1990, siehe ''[[Das Kindermädchen]]'':
„Smithee wurde allerdings auch nach ''Supernova'' gesichtet, in einem Film namens ''The Guardian''.“
-->

== Verwendung ==
Die Verwendung dieses oder eines anderen Pseudonyms ist für Mitglieder der DGA streng reglementiert. Ein Regisseur, der für einen von ihm gedrehten Film seinen Namen nicht hergeben möchte, hat nach Sichtung des fertigen Films drei Tage Zeit, anzuzeigen, dass er ein Pseudonym verwenden möchte. Der Rat der DGA entscheidet binnen zwei Tagen über das Anliegen. Erhebt die Produktionsfirma Einspruch, entscheidet ein Komitee aus Mitgliedern der DGA und der Vereinigung der Film- und Fernsehproduzenten, ob der Regisseur ein Pseudonym angeben darf. Über die Beantragung muss der Regisseur Stillschweigen halten, ebenso darf er den fertigen Film nicht öffentlich kritisieren, wenn die DGA ihm die Verwendung eines Pseudonyms zugesteht.<ref>Siehe zu diesen Regelungen [http://www.dga.org/~/media/Files/Contracts/Agreements/2008%20BA/008ba2008article8.pdf Artikel 8, Abschnitt 8-211 des ''Basic Agreement''] (PDF; 125&nbsp;kB) der DGA von 2008, abgerufen am 25. April 2012.</ref> Ein Antrag des Regisseurs auf Pseudonymisierung kann abgelehnt werden, so durfte [[Tony Kaye (Regisseur)|Tony Kaye]] den Namen Smithee bei dem Film ''[[American History X]]'' nicht einsetzen, obwohl er den Antrag stellte.

Auch bei nicht-US-amerikanischen Produktionen wird der Name verwendet, wie etwa beim [[Pilotfilm]] der Fernsehserie ''[[Schulmädchen (Fernsehserie)|Schulmädchen]]''. 2007 sendete die ARD am 8. und 9. August den zweiteiligen TV-Film ''Paparazzo''. Auch in diesem Werk erscheint anstatt des eigentlichen Regisseurs [[Stephan Wagner (Regisseur)|Stephan Wagner]] Alan Smithee im Abspann.

Regisseure, die das Pseudonym benutzt haben:
* [[Don Siegel]] und [[Robert Totten]] (für ''[[Frank Patch – Deine Stunden sind gezählt]]'')
* [[David Lynch]] (für die dreistündige Fernsehfassung von ''[[Der Wüstenplanet (Film)|Der Wüstenplanet]]'')
* [[Chris Christensen]] (''The Omega Imperative'')
* [[Gianni Bozzacchi]] (für ''I Love N.Y.'')
* [[Stuart Rosenberg]] (für ''Let’s Get Harry'')
* [[Richard C. Sarafian]] (für ''[[Starfire]]'')
* [[Dennis Hopper]] (für ''[[Catchfire]]'')
* [[Arthur Hiller (Regisseur)|Arthur Hiller]] (für ''[[Fahr zur Hölle Hollywood]]'')
* [[Rick Rosenthal]] (''Die Vögel II – Die Rückkehr'')
* [[Kevin Yagher]] (''[[Hellraiser IV – Bloodline]]'')
* [[William Lustig]] (''[[Maniac Cop 3]]'')
```

I wrote the following code:

```
import re
with open('C:\\path\\text.txt', encoding="unicode_escape") as f, open('word_list.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f1:
    f1.write('\n'.join(set(re.findall("[a-zA-Z_äöüÄÖÜß]+", f.read()))))
```

A text editor says I have 741 words, but the output only has approximately 460 words. The output looks like this (this is just a snippet) and it also contains single letters or groups of letters that don't make sense:

```
Hill
Himbeere
An
never
gepr
Frank
X
Eigener
Thee
Auch
anstatt
com
mehr
fiktiven
```

Should I use something else? Should I alter anything in my code? Is there a better way to filter such a messy text?

Comment: What exactly is a "word"? Should `1968` be counted? Because your regex is ignoring numbers. Should `Western-Film` be one word, or two? Because your regex is ignoring hyphens. What about `I’m`, should that be counted as zero one or two words? Currently it's counted as two, because your pattern is ignoring apostrophes.

Comment: Your input text also clearly has some markdown associated with links, e.g. `[[Supernova (2000)|Supernova]]`. You might want to add some custom handling to this, so only the actual visible words on the document are counted??

Comment: I am trying to count only nouns, adjectives, verbs and adverbs. Indeed I have to pay attention to what regex is ignoring.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is working correctly. Note that a set only keeps unique element, so that might be the reason for your lower wordcount.

In texts like these you will find many proper names and metadata words. In this one there is even a section where names are separated into syllables, which gives you some nonsensical results.

Depending on what you plan on doing with the data, it might be worth considering to get a dictionary of german words and discard any results that don't appear in the dictionary. There are some nice word lists in [this answer from the german stackexchange](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/491/where-can-i-find-a-parsable-list-of-german-words).

Comment: Thank you! What I want to do in the end is to try to determine what words are probably terminology/jargon. I am working with Wikipedia texts and by counting how many times each word appears, I determine how popular that word is. For example "dog" in comparison with "appendectomy". This is obv just a hypothesis and right now I'm just trying to filter the words and count them.

Comment: Then you are probably only interested in "actual" words, right? Also a lot of filler words and articles will rank highly ("und", "der", "die", "das", "er", "sie"...)

Comment: indeed, but that shouldn't be a problem because I can filter the stopwords afterwards. Maybe an aspect that I need to keep in mind is derived words that might appear, like plurals, various verb tenses and forms etc.

Comment: This is really a matter of how much time you want to invest. You might be able to group words together if they are similar, for example. The first word list from the linked post is alphabetically ordered - maybe you could group consecutive words if they have a low enough Levenshtein distance to get a good estimate. Sounds like a fun project!

Comment: Checking against a dictionary will not work, as that list will not contain any inflected words, and German is a tad more inflected than eg English.

Comment: @OliverMason The first dictionary (or rather word list) in the post I linked is meant for spellchecking and contains all inflected forms

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to work with wikipedia articles, you can use the wikipedia module. It imports the articles without the markdown information that is making you problems at the moment.

```
import wikipedia

page = wikipedia.page('Stack Overflow')
raw_text = page.content
```

Furthermore I would recommend you the Stutgart Tübingen Tagset which is used in the spacy module for instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I want all the Wikipedia articles in German, which I already have, so the module isn't really useful as far as I know.

Comment: hm ok. I see. It should be possible to itterate through the page IDs tho. Than you can extract german content only. That will take some time but it might be worth a shot since you would get proper data. Here's the link for the doc: https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#module-wikipedia